# How to get an already existing file (on my computer) in my method and convert it to InputStream?

Tags: java

I've a generated file in D:/EXPORT_BASE/Export_report. What I need to do is use the filePath string to fetch this file from my local, and then convert this to InputStream.

`String filePath = D:/EXPORT_BASE/Export_report/1557834965979_report.txt`

I need to use the String to get the file and write it to InputStream.

Comment: Before to post questions, you should try to look for the answer at least in Google, this only needs to know a little bit from java.io. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html

Comment: A *little* bit of research would have pointed you at the answer, e.g. [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, like this:

```
public InputStream getInputStreamFromFilepath(String filepath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File fileToOpen = new File(filepath);
    return new FileInputStream(fileToOpen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        File file = new File("C:/myTest.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                    + fis.available());

            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                // convert to char and display it
                System.out.print((char) content);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```